# How to link a static library without debugging symbols to an executable with debugging on VS 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

I want to get rid of some compiler warnings that I get when linking together a third party static library with my project. I compile it in debug mode all the time since I'm developing it, but the third party lib is an external library without the symbols.

The compiler shows the following warnings: `warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with ...`

Can I resolve this warning without ignoring it? Why would I need to link the static libraries with debugging symbols anyway if I don't need to debug them.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from here: [Linker Tools Warning LNK4099](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7whw3f3%28VS.80%29.aspx)

> You could also compile with `/Z7`, so the pdb doesn't need to be used, or remove the `/DEBUG` linker option if you do not have .pdb files for the objects you are linking.

Comment: Can this be done per static library we're linking or is it a global setting that applies to all the static libraries we're linking in?

Comment: I don't know. Try applying to the start up project and see the command line section of the project properties to see how it is specified.